# iphone, uiwebview with JS (google maps API)

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

two question for you:

reading google documentation i've make an html with the JS for make a google maps api call.
I've put this file in my project, and in a TABView i read and render this file in a uiwebview.
Works great but every time i start my app and go to this view i got this message: "appleweb://someID want to use your current location".
Is my fault or is normal? why my authrization is not saved in position auth?

Second: if i must make some other request on my map and passing new data or refreshing existent data is better that i do this via javascript or there's some option in cocoa to refresh my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is surely not your FAULT, and yes it is normal. user location authorization SHOULD NOT be saved because the next time user launches his app he wont be knowing that his current location is being used (just in case he wants to avoid that for whatever reason).

I dont know the answer to you second question but just a suggestion: why don't you use MapKit API provided by apple instead of going with html and js for google maps? It is pretty easy to use and theres enough documentation and sample codes available on [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/).

Comment: thank's for your reply.
i'm going to use this solution only for the simple ability to add polylines between two markers, this possibilities is not native support in mapkit.
i've see some project that draw polylines on an overlayed view but for me the code is not very understandable :D